# Why is it that Google PageSpeed Insights is not consistent

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I am trying to decide what template works best for my website, as I have about 50 to choose from. To assist in this decision, I am using PageSpeed Insights.

I have tested a few templates, where nothing but the template is changed and I recorded the results. This means that all of my content stays exactly the same.

As I was testing about the 10th or 12th one, I thought some of the numbers looked fishy and I decided to return to some of the first templates I had tested. The scores the second time I tested these first templates were SIGNIFICANTLY different. Sometimes better and sometimes worse, but almost always very different.

Is there a better place to test with some more reliable/repeatable numbers to help me in this decision?

Answer (score 0):

Try `webpagetest.org`, `gtmetrix.com`, `tools.pingdom.com` et al.

Note that if you are on shared hosting then resources available to serve your site may vary from test run to test run and thus influence results.